# Allowing IP range in Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-firewall

I installed Windows 7 on my main machine and Windows Firewall is causing havoc with my home network.  I can't seem to connect to the main machine running Windows Firewall from any other machines on my network.  I've used Zone Alarm in the past and it was easy to configure an IP range to get through, but I can't seem to find that in Windows Firewall config.

Any advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Control panel > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings (in the left side panel). This Opens up an mmc window for advanced firewall configuration.
In the left  panel, choose Inbound or Outbound rules.
Right panel, click New rule.
In the dialog, choose "custom".
In the left again, go to "Scope." When you add an IP, you can add a range.

Comment: Note that in the 1st group (local IP addresses) you define interfaces which are allowed to be used. In the 2nd group (remote IP addresses) you define actual computers that are allowed to connect. Which is kind of confusing.